# Is the Google Nexus program dead?

Tags: nexus

Has Google dumped the Nexus program?

The Pixel is more than double the cost of the previous generation (5X /6P) - nor does it carry the "Nexus" name.

Historically they have released a "Vanilla" phone as a tech showcase and developer friendly price-point approximately annually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Google Nexus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Nexus) wiki:

> With the expansion of the Google Pixel product line in late 2016, Google stated that they "don’t want to close a door completely, but there is no plan right now to do more Nexus devices."